# Mozilla Firefox: show/hide triggers a mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, firefox, mouseevent

Let's say you have a `<div>` element which is hidden.

There is a **mouseover** event attached to it and the mouse cursor is placed at the location where the `<div>` element will appear once it is visible.

How I can prevent the **mouseover** event from firing when the `<div>` is made visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The event is fired when the mouse is over a new element in Gecko, whether due to the mouse moving or elements moving.  This is quite purposeful; it makes things like CSS `:hover` work correctly when the mouse is not moving.

Comment: @bozhidarc no problem.  Note that in some other browsers `:hover` in fact does NOT update correctly when elements move...